# Cronjob command not working, despite having the same format as other commands that DO work

Tags: linux, unix, cron, vps

Trying to add a new cronjob to my server using Plesk. I have two running already, but it's so long since I set them up that I can't remember why I did it the way I did. They work exactly as they should.

```
*/13*   *   *   *   &> /dev/null php -q httpdocs/forum/notifyreply.php
*/9 *   *   *   *   &> /dev/null php -q httpdocs/forum/notifytopic.php
```

However, when I add my new job using the same format, it doesn't seem to do anything. The script doesn't run and I get no e-mail notification to tell me that the script has run. The new job is as follows:

```
*   *   *   *   *   &> /dev/null php -q httpdocs/crm/autoMessages/autoEmail.php
```

I'm running these on a Linux Virtual Server with Apache and using Plesk Control Panel. Hosting provider is 123-Reg.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So I've now removed the /dev/null line so I receive e-mail notifications and I'm getting the following error message:

`/bin/sh: php: Permission denied`

What I don't understand is why permission is being denied on this command but not on the other two...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what could have happened, but first thing I would do is to check if the permissions for the new php script are the same as what the old ones have.  Do a `ls -l` on both `httpdocs/forum/notifyreply.php` and `httpdocs/forum/notifytopic.php`, and compare the permissions against what `httpdocs/crm/autoMessages/autoEmail.php` have.

Comment: Had a look at the permissions and they appear to be identical. I've also taken out the /dev/null line so I'm receiving e-mails when the job is run and I'm getting the following error:  `Could not open input file: mysite.org.uk/httpdocs/crm/autoMessages/autoEmail.php`

Comment: Another update - see main post - thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a User/Group for the cron command, better do it like this

```
*   *   *   *   * www-data www-data   php -q httpdocs/crm/autoMessages/autoEmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

(assuming that www-data is the correct User)

note that I put the error handling at the end.
Also, I think that you should use the full path; either you forgot to add a slash  ( /httpdocs/.... ) , or do you have this script in the cron folder?